# Link to user profile with recent questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hyperlinks, users

Is it possible to get a link to the activity section of the user profile with recent questions and answers?

For example, if I enter the link, https://math.stackexchange.com/users/223599/sooraj-s?tab=topactivity, this redirects to the activity section of my Mathematics Stack Exchange profile, but which questions and answers are shown is based on their score.

It was helpful if it is possible to generate a link that redirects to the user profile showing recent questions and answers, which would be more relevant when added on a cv.

Comment: Is two links OK? [Recent questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/223599/sooraj-s?tab=questions&sort=newest) and [recent answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/223599/sooraj-s?tab=answers&sort=newest).

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for responding. I was looking for a link to the activity section of the user profile in the form you get when clicked on "Newest" option.

Comment: @VLAZ In https://math.stackexchange.com/users/223599/sooraj-s?tab=topactivity, both questions and answers are arranged based on the score, I want a link to the same page but both questions and answers arranged based on the date of posting.

Answer (score 1):

Which tabs are visible is set via JavaScript, in order to have it remembered on *your* profile (i.e. the user viewing the page). When you visit another user profile, you will see that the same tabs remain selected.

It is therefore not possible to provide a link which does what you want. If you want a list of a user's latest contributions, you'll have to resort to the search page: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a223599, which does have a `tab` parameter. It does show questions and answers intermingled, and it may show only/mostly one type of posts, depending on the activity of the user. So I can't judge whether that would work for your purposes.

Comment: Fine. But isn't it useful to have such a feature if we think about adding a StackExchange profile on a cv? If more recent posts are relevant to the application, which is a highly probable case, such a feature would easily give a glimpse of the user's contributions in the forum to the admission committee or the interviewer in a minute.

Comment: *If more recent posts are relevant to the application, which is a highly probable case* - ehm ... no? I'd rather look at a user's overall contribution; what if the user most recently participated in a low-traffic area with few votes? Does that really deserve to be more visible than the excellent questions/answers they made in the past? There's a reason that Score is the default selection on the profile page, and [Top Questions / Answers](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) on the network profile page ...

Comment: @SoorajS "*if we think about adding a StackExchange profile on a cv? If more recent posts are relevant to the application*" remember that the links aren't set in stone. What if somebody decides to open that CV a week later, or a month later, or next year. Then the "newest" won't really match up at the time when you made the CV. Moreover, that means you also have to restrict yourself to posting only on things relevant for the application for a while. Realistically, if you want to showcase given content, then directly mention it. If you add your profile then you're inviting people to see all.

Comment: @SoorajS If you want a link you can still give them a search for all posts by you for a tag or a set of tags, for example. That will have a lot less change to rot.